# Two very similar queries that returns a different result, why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going mad with this 2 queries, I can't explain myself why one returns 81 rows and the other 0. Can someone help me with this?

```
-- Working
SELECT * FROM
boat_standard_specification_items AS BoatStandardSpecificationItem JOIN standard_specification_items AS StandardSpecificationItem
ON(BoatStandardSpecificationItem.standard_specification_item_id = StandardSpecificationItem .id)

-- Not working
SELECT * FROM
`boat_standard_specification_items` AS `BoatStandardSpecificationItem` JOIN `standard_specification_items` AS `StandardSpecificationItem`
ON (`BoatStandardSpecificationItem`.`standard_specification_item_id` = 'StandardSpecificationItem.id')
```

I'm on Windows OS if can be helpful in any way

Comment: I don't think the results are the points here, the problem was that I were obtaining a <81 rows> result and a <0 rows> result, which means the query didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not the same query. On the second one, you have:

```
ON (`BoatStandardSpecificationItem`.`standard_specification_item_id` = 'StandardSpecificationItem.id')
                                                                       ^---
```

Note that change in quotes. Single quotes define a STRING in a query, so you're not comparing two fields, you're comparing a field against a string.

Comment: Oh man... I need a syntax highlighter, I found the error the exact moment I read my own question on stackoverflow... (well it's written through a php framework so I can be a bit excused)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the table names inside single quotes. Use [ and ] if you want to put something around them in order to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

In the second query

```
`BoatStandardSpecificationItem`.`standard_specification_item_id` = 'StandardSpecificationItem.id'
```

you are comparing `BoatStandardSpecificationItem`.`standard_specification_item_id`  with a string `'StandardSpecificationItem.id'`

In the first query

```
SELECT * FROM
boat_standard_specification_items AS BoatStandardSpecificationItem JOIN standard_specification_items AS StandardSpecificationItem
ON(BoatStandardSpecificationItem.standard_specification_item_id = StandardSpecificationItem .id)
```

you are comparing `BoatStandardSpecificationItem`.`standard_specification_item_id` with another column `StandardSpecificationItem .id`

It is so obvious they return different results

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the one that's "not working" is using a literal string to JOIN on (note the single quotes).  The rest of your query is using back-ticks, so try that once.

Answer (score 0):

They are different queries .In second you are trying to match field to a String which you might not want.

```
(`BoatStandardSpecificationItem`.`standard_specification_item_id` = 'StandardSpecificationItem.id')
```

you may learn more about [Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)